# Looking for a PHP driver based Cache Wrapper

Tags: php, caching

I am searching for a solution to code cache independent PHP code.

Some kind of Class or Library that provides a cache independent Layer.

So i can start coding and use a file based cache on the beginning and switch to apc/eaccellerator/memcached when the projects load goes up.

I know, thats not hard to code on your own, but thats also the reason why i believe that something like this already exists. And i would prefer using an already tested solution :)

Thanks in advance for you input!

Edit:
Sorry guys, but i need a standalone library which should play along nice with existing structures.

Comment: Take a look: https://github.com/fluxbb/cache

Comment: @sexyprout I dont want to steal your time, but if you want proper credit for your answer please post it as answer... At the time of this writing your hint is the best solution for my request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That of FluxBB: https://github.com/fluxbb/cache

Answer (score 2):

This kind of solutions should exist in pretty much any PHP Framework.

For a couple of examples

- With Zend Framework, you can use [**`Zend_Cache`**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.html) : switching from one [backend](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.backends.html) to another is just a matter of configuration.
- There is something that looks like an equivalent for Kohana : [About Kohana Cache](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/cache)
- And here's symfony's one : [sfCache Class](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfCache)

Answer (score 2):

CodeIgniter has a good [cache driver](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/caching.html).

Answer (score 0):

Why not create your own cache system, its not really that complex, just have a structure to load drivers, have an API Interface to implement and you should be good

```
class PHPCache
{
    protected $Driver;
    public function __construct($driver)
    {
        require_once 'drivers/' . $drivers . '.driver.php';
        $driver = "PHPCacheDriver_" . $driver;

        $this->Driver = new $driver;
    }


    public function create($key,$value)
    {
        return $this->Driver->create($key,$value);
    }

    public function read($key,$value)
    {
        return $this->Driver->read($key,$value);
    }

    public function update($key,$value)
    {
         return $this->Driver->update($key,$value);
    }

    public function remove($key)
    {
        return $this->Driver->remove($key);
    }
}
```

And then each driver implement an interface and CRUD the data accordingly.

Comment: I know that ist not hard, thats why i am thinking that someone probably did it before...

Comment: It is hard to implement it correctly. What about concurrent accesses to the same nonexisting cache? Getting that right is tricky if you want locking and everything.

Answer (score 0):

PEAR has the [Cache](http://pear.php.net/package/Cache) package, which has containers for:

- Database (PEAR DB lib, PEAR MDB2 lib, PHPlib db)
- File
- shared memory (SHM)
- [msession](http://de.php.net/manual/en/intro.msession.php)

PEAR's [Cache_Lite](http://pear.php.net/package/Cache_Lite) uses files only.