# File Cache Library for PHP

Tags: php, caching

Could you recommend me any good PHP written File-Cache library which is up2date (PHP >= 5)?

Comment: What do you mean when you're referring to a file cache?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for a PHP driver based Cache Wrapper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133350/looking-for-a-php-driver-based-cache-wrapper)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PEAR's [Cache_lite](http://pear.php.net/package/Cache_Lite/redirected) works well, even if is based (and compatible with) PHP 4, as most pear packages.