# How can I clear all cached objects using Cache::FileCache?

Tags: perl, mod-perl

I am using [`Cache::FileCache`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Cache%3a%3aFileCache) and the cache stored in `/tmp/FileCache/`

In the `/tmp/FileCache/` there are 3 dirs:

- `__AUTO_PURGE__`
- `Default`
- `namespace`

Which one is safe to deletes to clear the cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Cache::FileCache`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Cache%3a%3aFileCache) implements the [`Cache::Cache`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Cache%3a%3aCache) interface.

Instead of messing directly with the filesystem, you might want to write a short script such as

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Cache::FileCache;

my $cache = Cache::FileCache->new(
   {namespace => 'whatever namespace you are using'}
);
$cache->clear; # or Clear to remove all objects from all caches of this type.
```

Comment: Perfect.. got it work :) Thanks! Did there any PHP script that does similar to Cache::FileCache?

Comment: Thanks. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869420/file-cache-library-for-php and the linked question there.